# Mule Xpath for soap response

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I have the below soap response and i want to get the status value from the xml using the xpath.

```
soap:Envelope
soap:Body
ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResponse xmlns="http://www.compdata.com.au/"
ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResult
ConnoteSourceImportResponse xmlns=""
ProcessTime 2014-05-29T22:12:50+1000 ProcessTime
Status Success Status
Message Connote Import Success Message
ConnoteSourceImportResponse
ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResult
ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResponse
soap:Body
soap:Envelope
```

`xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`

added namespaces to mule config file as below

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Mule XPATH expression to get the status from your XML is as below

```
#[xpath('//comp:ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResponse/comp:ProcessMTUConsignmentSourceResult/comp:ConnoteSourceImportResponse/comp:Status').text]
```

Before that add the namespaces to the Mule Namespace Manager

```
<mule-xml:namespace-manager>
    <mule-xml:namespace prefix="soap"
        uri="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />
    <mule-xml:namespace prefix="comp"
        uri="http://www.compdata.com.au/" />
</mule-xml:namespace-manager>
```

Hope this helps.